# Import data from .txt file into SampleDataSource.cs Windows8 grid app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, datasource, readfile

I am building a windows grid app (VB 2012 C#) and trying to edit information in my SampleDataSource.cs. I have a lot of information to add and wanted to read in information from a .txt file instead of using String.Format() every time. I got this far however it is not working, keeps giving me the error "SampleDataSource': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type". I am worried to change the name of the class as this is all auto-generated code. How can I read in contents fromm a .txt file?

```
    public static string ITEM_CONTENT = "";

    public static async Task readTextFileContents(string fileLocation) {
        var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileLocation);
        var result = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        ITEM_CONTENT = result.ToString();
     }


    public async Task SampleDataSource()
    {
        await readTextFileContents("Text_Files/warmup_description.txt");
        var group1 = new SampleDataGroup("Group-1",
                "Warmup",
                "Group Subtitle: 1",
                "Assets/DarkGray.png",
                 ITEM_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

your this is part is wrong..

```
public async Task SampleDataSource()
{
    await readTextFileContents("Text_Files/warmup_description.txt");
    var group1 = new SampleDataGroup("Group-1",
            "Warmup",
            "Group Subtitle: 1",
            "Assets/DarkGray.png",
             ITEM_CONTENT);
```

you can add return type to your constructor you can read file in some other method..